# Waypoints start animation css

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-waypoints

I have a problem with starting animation with [waypoints.js.](http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/#get-started)

**http://codepen.io/Hackrosky/pen/Jjnai**

html:

```
<div class="div1"></div>
<div class="div2">
  <div id="smalldiv" class="fadeInUp"></div>
</div>
```

How can i made `<div id="smalldiv">` to fade in, with use of [waypoints.js](http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/#get-started)?

Comment: if this is too broad, why then can i provide an valid answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in waypoints, you have a callback, there is where the magic happens:

```
$('.div2').waypoint(function() {
  $('#smalldiv').fadeIn();
  },{offset: '80%'} //meaning, when .div2 is 80% in view from bottom
);
```

i see in your codepen, keyframes, no need to do it.

Comment: What exactly did you solve? can't see a difference in the pen after adding your code